# for a UIViewController which methods should a "release" and set to "nil" the outlets/instance variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

for a UIViewController which methods should a "release" and set to "nil" the outlets/instance variables?

That which of the methods out of "viewDidUnload" and "dealloc" should I be putting:

1. The "release" for outlets or other member variables in the class, and
2. The "xxx = nil" (i.e. set to nil) in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidUnload typical practice is to nil, using accessors, any objects embedded in the view controller's view - buttons, views, textfields, any descendant of UIView that could be in the view hierarchy:

```
self.myButton = nil;
```

In dealloc you should release ALL retained variables directly, including subviews:

```
[myButton release];
[someStateObject release];
```

Comment: thanks - I've got controllers where I have "released" then "nil'ed" variables in dealloc - would this be OK?  if not any ideas what issues could occur?

Comment: Why exactly should these be done differently? Generally if I have retain properties I tend to always nil them because it is safer in case of a double release. Can you explain any case where self.myButton = nil; would cause a problem?

Comment: @Greg In dealloc, some people will nil variables after releasing in case other code tries to access it but has not retained the value. There is nothing wrong with doing that. Personally I think it is overkill.

Comment: @skorulis You should not use accessors in dealloc. You cannot assume you know exactly what is going on inside an accessor, especially if your class is extended. An accessor might depend upon a completely valid object, which is often not the case inside dealloc. However, some might disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in `-dealloc`, you should use the ivars directly; in other cases as like `-viewDidUnload`, you’ll want to nil the properties.